# What is the difference between "state of the art" and "state-of-the-art"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, hyphens

Sometimes I see sentences with "state of the art" and others with "state-of-the-art".

What is the difference if it has a hyphen?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/state-of-the-art - no difference, Personally, I would use "state-of-the-art" as an adjective, and the other one as a noun

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that without hyphens, it's a noun, and with hyphens, it's an adjective.  So you might say that a given piece of technology "represents the state of the art in its field," or you could refer to it as "state-of-the-art technology."

"state of the art" is a noun: it refers to the actual state of progress in a given field.

> The most recent stage in the development of a product, incorporating the newest technology, ideas, and features
>
> *the state of the art in 3D printing*

"state-of-the-art" is a [compound adjective](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/compound-adjectives/): it refers to something (often a product or piece of technology) that uses the latest technology in a given field.

> Belonging or relating to the most recent stage of technological development; having or using the latest techniques or equipment.
>
> *our scientists work in state-of-the-art facilities*

Quoted definitions and example sentences are from [Oxford Dictionaries (via Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/state_of_the_art)

Comment: I'd appreciate any feedback on how this answer could be improved.

Comment: They probably downvoted your answer because it provides no dictionary for your claim of the use of the phrase as a noun and as an adjective. Have you made up these examples yourself or have you found them somewhere? They are a bit awkward and do not help to explain your point very much. Try simpler sentences.

Comment: @fev Thank you very much for your input; it was quite helpful in seeing the issues.